# Data insertion errorColumn count doesn't match value count at row 1 in Mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some values into a mysql databas using php.The following is my php code.

```
<?php

        include "config.php";
        $dbname =$_POST["dbname"];
        $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);
         if(!$con)
         {
                         echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
         }
         else{
        //echo "";
         }

        $arrAssoc = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']), true);
        $values="";
        foreach($arrAssoc as $aa){
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($aa);exit;
                $values.="(";
                $values.=" '".$aa['ID']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['adv_no']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['date']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['custInfo']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['itembarcode']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['weight']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['gross_wt']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['stone_wt']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['stone_amt']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['rate']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['making']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['qty']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['item_total']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['sum_total']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['advance']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['balance']."' ";
                $values.=" '".$aa['time']."' ";
                $values.="),";
        }
        $values=rtrim($values,',');

        $query="INSERT INTO advance_order
        (ID,adv_no, date, custInfo, itembarcode,
        weight, gross_wt, stone_wt,stone_amt,
        rate,making,qty,item_total,sum_total,advance,balance,time)
        VALUES".$values;

        if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
        {
        echo "Data inserted";
        }else
        {
        echo "Data insertion error".mysqli_error($con);
        }


?>
```

> I am sending data to this php script from my android device.this is the database structure for the table I am inserting these values into.
>   [image]

My first column is Id which auto increments and the last column is time stamp with default value being the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP like `time` timestamp  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.Are the first and last column creating the problem.
I am new to php any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No need to explicitly add ID in the query since it is auto increment.

Comment: echo `$values` and check its values!!

Comment: @EdwinAlex I tried removing ID but i still get the same error.Can you please take a look at my code.Thank you.

Comment: @Saty this is what I get if I echo $values; RESPONSE: ( 'ADV100', '29-Feb-2016', 'yogesh 9536521245', 'BRMS4', '200', '0', '0', '0', '30719', '300', '', '', '721996.0', '0.0', '0.0'  '' ),( 'ADV100', '29-Feb-2016', 'yogesh 9536521245', 'BRMS3', '35', '0', '0', '0', '28733', '300', '', '', '721996.0', '0.0', '0.0'  '' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue..

Add `comma` after setting balance.

Because of missing comma, it treats both `balance` and `time` as a single value.

Try with the below piece of code.

```
$values.=" '".$aa['balance']."', ";
$values.=" '".$aa['time']."' ";
```